# Change endpoint logging behavior in Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, tornado

I'm using Tornado 5 to run a site with several endpoints. One of those endpoints is just for health checks and I really don't need that particular endpoint showing up in the logs every 2 seconds as a simple GET request.

Is there any way to disable logging for that single endpoint, or at least switch it to maybe a DEBUG log message rather than logging as INFO?

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `RequestHandler._log` method:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/fc6dd2345c3c8af0186765fc0396ff70e47c3022/tornado/web.py#L1725

Or for a more complex but arguably cleaner way, you can pass a `log_function` to your `Application` that inspects the handler and is a no-op for your health check handler.

Comment: I ended up doing the override. Thanks for the help!